# Webpack builded index.html served from express

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I had configured express to use **swig** as template engine and **/public** as views directory and in static middleware this way:

```
app.engine('html', engines.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Then i configured express app to listen for requests this way:

```
app.use('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index', {
       title: 'ciao'
    });
})
```

In my template i have something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css) { %>
        <link rel="preload" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[chunk] %>"  as="style">
    <% } %>
    <% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>
        <link rel="preload" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %>" as="script">
    <% } %>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But "title" is not replaced by "ciao" and is rendered as is.

This should be a common scenario so probably i'm missing something.
Thx for your help!!!! ;)

**SOLUTION**:

*!!! Be careful, this solution with expose your template to public access. (mysite.com/index.html will return your template) Btw this can be patched easily.*

Remove this:

```
app.engine('html', engines.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
```

Set index in static middleware:

```
app.use('',express.static('public',{
  index: '_',
}));
```

Instead `res.render` use:

```
app.use('/',(req,res)=>{
    return engines.swig(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {
        title: "Ciao",
        cache: true
    }).then((html)=>{
        return res.send(html);
    }).catch((err) => {
        throw err
    })
})
```

You need to install `npm i --save consolidate`

Basically you use `index.html` as a template and swig function mix swig template + data and return html.

I will investigate further if this solution impact on performance but should not!!

Comment: What does public contains? Are you also using webpack as a node api, or standalone?

Comment: Public contains the webpack build. I'm using webpack standalone to create the build. Thx